# Protege 4.2 and rule editor

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege, swrl

I am working on protege 4.2 and using rule editor with pellet reasoner, trying to write rules on rule editor, but not able to understand how i can deduce some inference or execute them and find out some conclusion like my rule is if person is having symptom fibrillation and muscle pain then he is suffering from disorder muscular_pain
how to write it using rules here fibrillation , muscle pain and muscular_pain all are individuals, but person is class

Comment: There's not enough information here yet to tell what you're trying to do.  Please provide some same data, and the rule that you're trying to encode.  Also, there are plenty of examples on StackOverflow already of writing SWRL rules in Protégé and inferring results such as:

Comment: [Ontology property definition in Protege-OWL / SWRL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21499126/1281433), [swrl rules to infer dataProperty values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15246550/1281433), [SWRL rules don't infer new Object and Data Property Assertions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21540839/1281433), [OWL 2 reasoning with SWRL rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17035238/1281433). In general, have a look at the questions tagged with [tag:swrl].